# ¿como situar en el centro del div horizontalmente con bootstrap5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

queria situar en el centro de la pantalla (horizontalmente) el texto "hola!". Recuerdo que antes con `justify-content-center` me funcionaba pero ahora no consigo posicionarlo. Pero la condicion es que la columna sea de 12, eso no se podria modificar.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row d-flex">
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-center bg-danger">
                    <h3>hola!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrego esta respuesta como corrección a la respuesta de @masterguru

La corrección debiese ser al `div` y no al `h3` como se sugiere, por que al momento de tener más elementos dentro, las cosas cambian. Y supongo que lo indicado por el OP, es el estilo al div, no al h3.

```
<div class="col-12 justify-content-center bg-danger text-center">
    <h3>hola!</h3>Texto aleatorio
    <div>otro div</div>
</div>
```

## CENTER DIV

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## CENTER H3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta, mi explicación no era correcta del todo.